# How does Conspirator work with Throne Room / King's Court?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue, dominion-prosperity

If, for example, my turn starts by playing a King's Court and choosing Conspirator, how many cards will I draw?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is explained in the [Intrigue rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_306_gameRules.pdf)

> **Conspirator** – You evaluate whether or not Conspirator gives you +1 Card and +1
>   Action when you play it. If later in the turn you play more Action cards, you do not go
>   back and reevaluate a Conspirator played earlier.
>
> For the purposes of counting actions,
>   if you Throne Room an Action, that's one Action for the Throne Room, one for the
>   selected Action played the first time, and one for the selected Action played the second
>   time. For example, if you play Throne Room on Conspirator, the first Conspirator will
>   be your second Action, and won't give you +1 Card or +1 Action, but the second
>   Conspirator will be your third Action, and you will get +1 Card and +1 Action for that
>   second Conspirator. Action - Victory cards are Actions

For your example, if you play King's Court and choose Conspirator, you would draw +2 cards and get +2 actions.  The first copy of Conspirator would count as your second action, and then the second and third plays would qualify.

The sequence would be:

1. Play [King's Court](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=king%27s%20court) (Action #1)
2. Choose [Conspirator](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=conspirator) (Choosing does not count as playing an action)
3. Play 1st Conspirator (Action #2 - no bonus from Conspirator)
4. Play 2nd Conspirator (Action #3 - receive bonus from Conspirator).
5. Play 3nd Conspirator (Action #4 - receive bonus from Conspirator).